# interview question rolling dice of posterior probability

Tags: probability

You have two 6-sided dice. You roll them and get a total of 10. You roll again and get a total of 9. If you get paid 1$ for each 5 that is rolled what is your expected winnings？

I guess it is the posterior probability：
$$P(X_3 = 5\ or\ Y_3 = 5\Big| X_2 + Y_2 = 9\ and\ X_1 + Y_1 = 10).$$

Here $X_i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ are i.i.d. and $Y_i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ are i.i.d. (But not sure if X, Y are i.i.d.？).

Comment: Unconditionally $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ and $Y_i$ are identically and independently distributed, but conditioned on the sums this ceases to be the position.  (What are $X_3,Y_3$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming fair dice, I believe the expected answer would be
$$E[I_{X_1=5} + I_{Y_1=5} + I_{X_2=5} + I_{Y_2=5} | X_1+Y_1=10, X_2+Y_2=9]$$
which is also
$$
E[I_{X_1=5} + I_{Y_1=5}| X_1+Y_1=10]
+
E[I_{X_1=5} + I_{Y_1=5}| X_1+Y_1=9]
= 2/3 + 2/4.
$$